# Angular $watch doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to watch a variable which I set in my service, and when it changes - I change a value in the controller, but the watch event isn't firing.

This is my code:

```
var module = angular.module("Test", []);
module.service("testService", TestService);
module.controller("testController", TestController);

function TestService()
{
    var self = this;
    self.Message = "1";
}

TestController.$inject =["$scope", "testService"];
function TestController($scope, testService)
{
    var self = this;
    self.Message = testService.Message;
    $scope.Message = self.Message;

    $scope.$watch("Message", onMessageChange, true)
    self.click = function()
    {
        testService.Message = "2";        
    }

    function onMessageChange(oldVal, newVal)
    {
        self.Message = newVal;
    }
}
```

and this is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>

     <script src=".\angular.js"></script>    
     <script src=".\test.js"></script>    
    </head>
    <body ng-app="Test">
   <div  ng-controller="testController as ctrl">
    <button  ng-click="ctrl.click()"> Click </button>
    <span> Message: {{ctrl.Message}}</span>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Why isn't it working? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: change it to <span> Message: {{Message}}</span>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can watch your service variable like that:

```
$scope.$watch(function() { return testService.Message;}, onMessageChange, true)
```

You also need to change oldVal and newVal:

```
function onMessageChange(newVal, oldVal)
{
    self.Message = newVal;
}
```

This code was only watching your $scope.Message not your service variable.

```
$scope.$watch("Message", onMessageChange, true)
```

It would only have fired when you change the variable in your click function, like that:

```
self.click = function()
{
    $scope.Message = "2";        
}
```

Comment: any idea as to why I need to return testService.Message from a function instead of just watching it?

Comment: if you pass testService.Message into $watch like that $scope.$watch("testService.Message", onMessageChange, true), testService.Message will get evaluated as a expression which returns undefined